# Trying to execute a dynamic CTE in PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, function, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a Postgresql function which will dynamically build the CTE and execute it to do the archive/purge.

Context: Records from main tables must be archived to their corresponding archive table and then deleted from the original table on a periodic basis. For this, tbl_archive_master table has the columns which have of the original table (from_tbl_name), the archive table (arch_tbl_name) and the where condition used (where_clause) to do the archive and purge.

Below is the function but it doesn't seem to execute CTE...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_f() 
RETURNS text
AS
$func$
DECLARE
  r record;
  q text;
BEGIN
   for r in
        select concat(from_tbl_schema,'.',from_tbl_name)::text as main_t_name, concat(arch_schema,'.',arch_tbl_name)::text as  arch_t_name, where_clause::text
        from axis.tbl_archive_master t
        where t.from_tbl_name = 'tbl_req_tracking_arch' and t.arch_tbl_name='tbl_req_tracking_arch2'
   loop
    q := format('with deleted_rows as (delete from %s where %s returning * ) insert into %s select deleted_rows.* from deleted_rows ;',r.main_t_name, r.where_clause, r.arch_t_name);
    raise notice '%', q;
    execute q;  -- this line fails
   end loop;
   perform 'end';
END;
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

...even though RAISE NOTICE shows it is populated fine.

```
Axis=# select some_f();
NOTICE:  with deleted_rows as (delete from axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch where "CREATE_DATE" <= (current_date - 30) returning * ) insert into axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch2 select deleted_rows.* from deleted_rows ;
ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function some_f()
```

But if I run the cte directly, it runs fine. In below case, there were no records in axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch to archive and purge.

```
Axis=# with deleted_rows as (delete from axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch where "CREATE_DATE" <= (current_date - 30) returning * ) insert into axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch2 select deleted_rows.* from deleted_rows ;
INSERT 0 0
Axis=#
```

Comment: Thats why I'm perform 'end' so it returns some text. How should I return a string? Also, when original table had records to purge, it wouldn't archive/purge them so execute step is not running.

Comment: `return 'end';`  but if it's just pointless return value, change the signature to `returns void` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks you @LaurenzAlbe and @Zegarek!! I changed it to return 'end' and now I can see the execute part is working.
Axis=# select some_f();
NOTICE:  with deleted_rows as (delete from axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch where "CREATE_DATE" <= (current_date - 30) returning * ) insert into axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch2 select deleted_rows.* from deleted_rows ;
 some_f
--------
 end
(1 row)

Axis=# select count(*) from axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch; select count(*) from axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch2;
 count
-------
  3709
(1 row)

 count
-------
 19620
(1 row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't complain about the `EXECUTE` line like you think, but about the lack of a `RETURN` statement that returns a `text`.  On the other hand, your `PERFORM` statement doesn't do anything useful. Perhaps you meant to say

```
RETURN 'end';
```

instead of

```
PERFORM 'end';
```

The latter statement just runs `SELECT 'end';`, then discards the result.

Comment: If I ran the CTE directly in psql, it gave me result as below...

Axis=#  with deleted_rows as (delete from axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch where "CREATE_DATE" <= (current_date - 30) returning * ) insert into axis.tbl_req_tracking_arch2 select deleted_rows.* from deleted_rows ;
INSERT 0 3631

How can I get the "INSERT 0 3631" when I use the execute command in above function? I tried with 

execute q into result_var; return result_var; 

but got this...

ERROR:  INTO used with a command that cannot return data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function some_f() line 18 at EXECUTE

Comment: That is unreadable, and should probably be a new question.